# Looking for solution on how to populate data into uitableviewcell that has two uiview

Tags: ios

I created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and  added two identical `UIView`s that have exactly  the same format.

MyTableViewCell:

```
 UIView *leftView    = [[UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 100)];
 UIView *rightView   = [[UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 100)]; 
 [self.contentView addSubview:leftView];
 [self.contentView addSubview:rightView];
```

Each time  I need to assign two values when `indexPath.row` indicates only one index. This is my current code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row %2) {
        cell.label1.text = [array  objectAtindex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.label2.text =[array  objectAtindex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"name"]; 
     }
}
```

Cell layout:

```
   |------------|--------------|
   |     1      |      2       |
   -----------------------------
   |     3      |      4       |
   -----------------------------
   |     5      |      6       |
   -----------------------------
```

The result is that cells 2,3,6 are empty and cells 1,4,5 filled. I have no idea how to populate data into the two same UIViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `array` contains exactly twice as many items as the table has rows, it should work like this:

```
NSUInteger indexForField1 = indexPath.row * 2;
NSUInteger indexForField2 = indexPath.row * 2 + 1;
cell.label1.text = [array  objectAtindex:indexForField1]  objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.label2.text =[array  objectAtindex:indexForField2]  objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Then you should accept ths answer (click the checkmark beside it).